# can we query multiple times on a model in the same view in Django?

Tags: python, django

I have been working on a video sharing website. I am using Django 1.6. There is a page where a user can watch any particular video. Also, a section of 'Popular videos' is right alongside wherein popular videos are listed based on the number of views. I want to know if we can query the same model multiple times in a single view function or not. My code is as below..

```
def watch(request, video_id):
      video_to_watch = Video.objects.get(id=video_id)
      popular_videos = Video.objects.filter(views__gt=100)
```

Comment: django 1.6 is no longer supported btw, If you're starting now, start with 1.8, or 1.7 if there are no tutorials for 1.8 yet.

Answer (score 1):

Yes, you can query the same model in a single view as many times as you want.

Comment: thanks catavaran but when i try to pass in the popular_videos context into the template , it doesn't show up as {% for video in popular_videos %} 
{{ video.track_name }}

{% endfor %}

Comment: Add the `print popular_videos` statement to the view and look to the output of the devserver console.  Is this list empty?

Answer (score 0):

yes you can query one model multiple times. The best way for your scenario is to use model manager.

```
class PopularManager(models.Manager):
    def get_queryset(self):
        return super(PopularManager, self).get_queryset().filter(views__gt=100)

class Video(models.Model)
    ....
    popular = PopularManager()
```

You can get popular videos like this.

```
popular_videos = Video.popular.all()
```

Comment: thanks friends for your sincere help, now it's all working as expected.

Comment: ah thanx you can use up vote if you think this answer is usefull